# Answering your own question?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why aren’t people answering their own questions?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304/why-arent-people-answering-their-own-questions)

I was reading through the discussions on [the lack of expert content](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195/should-we-worry-about-the-amount-of-non-expert-content-on-the-site?rq=1) and on [answering your own questions](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/304/1306). In most SE sites this kind of posting is actively encouraged. I also think it is a good idea that each of us shares our knowledge in a Q&A format this way. I believe it will help attract visitors to the site.

So, to that end I have asked and answered a [question on para- vs orthologs](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/4962/1306), two terms that are very often misused in the literature and in Lab Meetings around the world.

Is the community OK with this? Do you all think we should go ahead and post these kinds of question/answers? Would you prefer I removed my answer or put it into Community Wiki mode?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/92/is-wikipedia-authoring-here-necessary-and-allowed) and I think [duplicate](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/304/why-arent-people-answering-their-own-questions)